# htaccess redirecionamento 301 URL que não existe

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Existia um site antigo e todas suas URLs foram alteradas.

Uma URL que era bem encontrada no Google era:

meudominio.com/datacenters

Agora quero redirecionar essa URL para:

meudominio.com/data-centers

No htaccess fiz:

```
redirect 301 /datacenters /data-centers
```

Mas não vai, o que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma de deve dar certo.

```
Redirect 301 /meudominio.com/datacenters.html http://meudominio.com/data-centers.html
```

Outro exemplo: Redirecionamento 301 com .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /diretorio/antigo_arquivo.htm http://www.exemplo.com.br/novo_arquivo.htm

Redirect 301 /pagina-antiga.html http://meudominio.com/folder/
```

Link de referência https://www.carti.com.br/como-fazer-redirecionamento-301/

Comment: Não vai.... já tinha visto este exemplo. A URL do navegador continua a mesma (a que não existe mais)

Comment: @caiocafardo da uma olhada no segundo exemplo. Olha se funciona `Redirect 301 /pagina-antiga.html http://meudominio.com/folder/`

Comment: Também não... o certo era qualquer coisa que eu colocasse '/teste' deveria redirecionar para a URL que está depois, certo?

Comment: Aqui tem um artigo super curto, só com exemplos diretos. Se dessa forma não der certo, não vou saber te ajudar... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/